# What does this statement do: ();

Tags: perl

I've seen perl statements that look like this:

```
() unless $some_var;
```

What is that intended to achieve?

Comment: Please show the actual script containing this statement.

Comment: Include some more code from your script to understand it properly, that in which context () is used.

Answer (score 9):

There's a couple of things going on here, but most significant is the fact that this sort of line would usually appear as the last line of an executed block[1].  In that context, the value of the block is the value of the last executed statement[2].  Now a statement containing `unless` has the value of the left-hand side if the right-hand side is true and the value of the right-hand side otherwise, so this is a way of saying "the value of the block is `$some_var` if `$some_var` happens to be true, `()` otherwise".

`()` is merely the empty list, so this code is providing a default value of the empty list for cases where `$some_var` is false (probably because `$some_var` is undefined.)

It is more usual to achieve the same effect with `or`, as in the equivalent

```
$some_var or ();
```

Put together, we can see these cases:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @x = do { () unless 0 };
my @y = do { () unless 5 };

print "\@x: <@x>\n\@y: <@y>\n";
```

`@x` is the empty array because `0` is false, whereas `@y` is an array containing `5` because `5` is true.

Anywhere other than as the last statement of a block, `() unless $some_var;` is a no-op.  It does suppress the `once` warning if `$some_var` is not otherwise mentioned, though.

[1]:  That's a block evaluated by `eval` or `do` or supplied to (for example) `map` or `grep`, or a block called as a subroutine.

[2]:  "The value of the last executed statement" is a weird phrase; mostly only expressions have values.  But because Perl includes the concept that in the absence of an explicit return the value of a block is the value of the last statement, Perl needs this weird phrase.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed analysis; doesn't seem to be what's happening here (if anything). Here's a bit more of a script, lots of subsequent code omitted, and it finally ends in an 'exit(0);' :
 #-- MAIN -----------------------------------------------------------------------
GetOptions( "-interactive",
            "-request_file=s", )
or usage();

usage unless ($opt_request_file);
() unless ($opt_interactive);

$today = strftime ".%Y-%m-%d", localtime;
$dte = strftime "%Y-%m-%d", localtime;
@col = ("M","N","O","P","Q","R","S");

. . .

Comment: Sorry if I formatted that badly, just cut and paste from putty, looked ok in this text box :-(

Comment: With that context, it looks like a no-op to me.  At a guess, the interactive option is actually unimplemented cruft, and the unless statement is in there as a place holder for some code that never got written.  I would not hesitate to remove it.

Comment: Given the incorrect use of Getopt::Long displayed in that code sample, an alternative explanation becomes likely:  The line is acting as as a way of suppressing a "used once" warning.  Given that this compiles, I would advise adding "use strict" in addition to getting rid of the crufty option.

Comment: This is really clever use of unless, albeit very obfuscated in my opinion. +1

Comment: Thank you, Karel, and thanks for wading through my unformatted code snippet!

Comment: Thank, darch - removing it doesn;t seem to cause any visible symptoms - trying to track down the author.

Comment: (Small correction:  The usage of Getopt::Long is not actually wrong.  It *is* useless, though.  Mea culpa, should have checked rather than just skimming the docs.)

Comment: And it's been my pleasure.  Now to sleep before I make another misstatement on a public forum. =P

Answer (score 3):

Mystery solved:

```
GetOptions(
    "-interactive",
    "-request_file=s",
) or usage();

usage unless ($opt_request_file);
() unless ($opt_interactive);
```

It seems the '();' is misleading - it does nothing, and the purpose is just to mention the $opt_interactive variable once... as a way to suppress the perl warning 'Name "$var" used only once'.

Thanks to all who tried to shed some light!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably used in implicit return, if `$some_var` evaluates to true, return it, otherwise return empty list.

Comment: Thanks - not sure how that can work, since it occurs at the start of a script, not in a subroutine, and the same script ends with an exit(0);

Comment: Keep in mind that when a subroutine exits the return value is the last value processed (or, if there is a `return` statement, whatever that `return` statement was called with).

Answer (score 1):

On itself, this expression is a nop. But the value (empty list) can be automatically returned from a subroutine or do() block, if there's no explicit return statement and this value happens to be the last thing in the block.

Comment: Thanks, I like this theory... but it is near the top of the main routine, a lot of stuff happens after it :-(

Answer (score 0):

**if** executes the statement once if and only if the condition is true.

`unless` is the opposite, it executes the statement unless the condition is true (i.e., if the condition is false).

see  for more detail: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html

() is merely the empty list, so this code is providing a default value of the empty list for cases where $some_var is false (probably because $some_var is undefined).

Comment: Thank you, I understand the 'unless' part - but why the '()'?  What does the empty list achieve?

Answer (score 0):

It returns empty list if $some_var is false.

If I write 
`@s = () unless $some_var;`, I emptied `@s` if `$some_var` is false.

That is the only way this can be used I can think of.

Comment: Thanks - sorry if I wasn't clear, but this is all by itself on a line - no assignment.